# autodesk-forge Bim 360 to Unity3d - create Unity scene has Size Limit?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

is there a Size Limit for Post Scene Job , Models up to 100 MB are loading in Unity, above 100Mb the manifest shows "succsess" but the Model is not loaded in Unity3d.

https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/2.0.0#/ARKit/assets_create

Did expect that the Post Scene Job works for larger Models(>100MB) too.
https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/2.0.0#/ARKit/assets_create

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a hard-coded size limit (I don't think there is) but due to the way the service is designed, what really matters here is the *complexity* of the design, not necessarily its file size. For example, you could have a design that's less than 100MB in size but it could contain so many individual design elements that trying to load it into Unity would take forever.

Btw if you're interested in bringing Forge designs to Unity, I would suggest that you look at an alternative approach - using the [forge-convert-utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils) library to convert Forge models into glTF, optimize the glTF using something like [gltfpack](https://meshoptimizer.org/gltf/), and load it into Unity using something like [glTFast](https://github.com/atteneder/glTFast). There's also a lightning talk video I recorded for Autodesk University 2022 where I explain this process in a bit more detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBNF42Ykajo.

Comment: Hi Petr, thanks for your replay, can i host this converter on my own server ans can automaticaly translate ACC(BIM 360) models? I tried it already with local server but i didnt get it to work.  Also  i need the models from Bim 360 projects not from  the normal bucket. I will take a look a look at the video, Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use the converter wherever you want, incl. your own servers. And it works with models from ACC/BIM360 as well. Basically all it needs is an SVF file, no matter whether it's been created from an OSS object (by you), or by ACC or BIM360.